# Performance Benchmarking for Apache Nutch

Tags: apache, search-engine, nutch

I want to know if there are any existing benchmarks and sizing information for an apache nutch based search engine deployment. I want to know for say 10 million searches a month what should be the hardware sizing that needs to deployed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the [nutch mailing list](http://lucene.apache.org/nutch/mailing_lists.html) could help you with this.

Comment: hi, could you highlight a specific thread, I have been searching the list for quite some time with no proper results on performance benchmarking.

Comment: I was thinking you could join and ask.